GCC C99 Disable compilation of main() without return
How to force gcc compilator throw error when int main() have no return statement. This code compiles without any errors
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
   printf("Hi");
}

I am using
gcc  -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -Wreturn-type -Werror -pedantic-errors a.c

command for compilation

GCC does not report an error because the code is not erroneous.

@JohnBollinger: GCC reports diagnostics for a number of things that are not erroneous and that do technically conform to the standard. That is normal and permitted by the standard. -Werror puts GCC into a non-conforming mode in which all diagnostics are errors. This shows it is invalid to reason that because some code is valid, GCC cannot have a switch to produce an error for it. For example, with OP’s switches, GCC rejects the strictly conforming code int foo(char *p, char x) { return p[x]; }.

Fine, @EricPostpischil: GCC does not report an error in this case because the code is not erroneous, and its meaning is unconditionally well-defined.  Or, if you want to get to the real nuts and bolts, because the GCC developers, presumably motivated by the above, do not consider this case to be one meriting any kind of diagnostic.  But I estimate that that explanation is not an improvement over "it's not erroneous" for the OP's purposes.

I would not be surprised if the GCC developers would accept a patch adding a new option, -Womitted-return-in-main or something like that, that made this a warning, particularly as the code was erroneous in C89 and some people do still care about keeping compatibility with that standard.  But I'm also not at all surprised no one has yet bothered implementing such a warning.

@zwol: It does not even need to be for old C compatibility. Somebody could intend to design their code so that every code path had an explicit return with a value consciously chosen by the author and hence would want and benefit from a warning that told them they had missed one (or some edit had broken the design), leading to an undesired implicit return with a value other than they desired.

@EricPostpischil I personally always write a return statement at the end of main and would use this option if it existed, even though I don't try to write C89-compliant code anymore; but the "this was ill-formed in C89" argument might help get the patch accepted.

@JohnBollinger "and its meaning is unconditionally well-defined"  Except it isn't. PC programmers tend to conveniently only look at half of the truth, namely the hosted system sub chapter. There's also 5.1.2.1 for freestanding systems. "The effect of program termination in a freestanding environment is implementation-defined."

@Den4ik The real question here is what you think such a warning would achieve. Do you need to be C89 compatible still?

You can avoid the special treatment that main receives by renaming it. Compiling with -Dmain=AlternateName -Werror=return-type yields “error: control reaches end of non-void function”.
Naturally, you would do this as a special compilation to test for the issue and not use the object module resulting from this compilation. A second normal compilation without -Dmain=AlternateName would be used to generate the object module.

This can't be disabled, as such behavior would be in violation of the C99 standard.
Section 5.1.2.2.3 of C99 states the following regarding the main function:

If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int,
a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to
calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function
as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the main function
returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int,
the termination status returned to the host environment is
unspecified.


It doesn't necessarily violate the C standard. You are only quoting the hosted system sub chapter. There is also 5.1.2.1 for freestanding systems: "The effect of program termination in a freestanding environment is implementation-defined." (The rationale is that returning from main() in a freestanding system is senseless.) So there may be a difference when compiling with a "conforming hosted implementation" vs a ""conforming freestanding implementation". In case of gcc, -ffreestanding doesn't change the diagnostics in this specific case though.

It is not possible as it correct in C99

5.1.2.2.3 Program termination 1 If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call
to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with
the value returned by the main function as its argument; 11) reaching
the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If the
return type is not compatible with int, the termination status
returned to the host environment is unspecified.


DV-ter - explain the DV

The C standard is voluntary. Compilers are not required to conform to it, and the fact that a feature does not conform to the standard does not mean a compiler does not have that feature. GCC has a number of features that do not conform to the C standard. In fact, the switches OP uses in the question, -Wall -Werror, put GCC into a non-conforming mode since then it refuses to compile some programs that would compile in a conforming compiler.
